# Gerar struct em matlab dinamicamente, com campos de tamanhos diferentes

Tags: matlab

Estou com uma demanda que é o seguinte, eu quero criar um conjunto de imagens e vou relacioná-las, para isso eu crio um vetor de struct similar a `resultsInfo = struct('indice',0,'correlatas',cell(1,5),'fatorCorrelacao',zeros(1,5),'somaImagens',zeros(640,480));`, onde:
indice é um inteiro representando o índice da imagem;
correlatas recebe célula com 5 nomes diferentes de imagens que são similares
fatorCorrelacao é um vetor que recebe um número que representa o quão similar são essas imagens;
e somaImagens recebe a soma das 5 imagens similares.

Quando faço isso, ele preenche as matrizes do campo somaImagem, apenas dos 5 primeiros elementos do vetor, os demais ele aloca uma matriz vazia. 
A minha intenção é preencher o vetor dinamicamente, pois o número de imagens pode variar de acordo com cada projeto.

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu resolver. Para ficar mais coesa a pergunta e sua resolução, sugiro que copie a solução e poste como resposta logo abaixo e marque no "v" como resolvida.

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, Diego

Answer (score 0):

Resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792600/generate-struct-in-matlab-with-fields-of-different-sizes)

Defina o seguinte método:

```
function resultStruct = CreateEmptySruct ()
    resultStruct.img_index = 0  ;
    resultStruct.correlated  = cell(1,5);
    resultStruct.correlationFactor = zeros(1,5);
    resultStruct.ImgSum = zeros(640,480) ;
end

Then call this method in For loop like this:

for i = 1 :5
    structArray(i) = CreateEmptySruct () ;
end
```

No entanto você pode definir também qualquer valor separadamente para cada `struct`, passando argumentos da função.

Comment: Boa tarde Daniel, quando disseram que era pra trazer a resposta do SOen, voce deveria ter traduzido ela, somos uma comunidade em Português, a sua duvida pode ser de outras pessoas, mas nem todo mundo sabe inglês.

Comment: Ok Guilherme, obrigado pela edição e pela orientação